# Using multiple BlockingCollection<T> buffers in implementing pipeline validation

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

So, I have a requirement to read each record(line) of a large data file and then application various validation rules on each of these lines. So, rather than just apply sequential validation, I decided to see if I could use some pipelining to help speed things up. So, I need to apply the same set of Business validation rules(5 at the moment) to all items in my collection. As there is no need to return output from each validation process, I don't need to worry about passing values from one validation routine to the other. I do however need to make the same data available to all my validation steps and to do this, I came up with coping the same data(records) to 5 different buffers, which will be used by each of the validation stages.

Below is the code I have going. But I have little confidence in this applied and wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this please? I appreciate any help you can give on this please. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void LoadBuffers(List<BlockingCollection<FlattenedLoadDetail>> outputs,
            BlockingCollection<StudentDetail> students)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var student in students)
                {
                    foreach (var stub in student.RecordYearDetails)
                        foreach (var buffer in outputs)
                            buffer.Add(stub);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                 foreach (var buffer in outputs)
                     buffer.CompleteAdding();
            }

        }


    public void Process(BlockingCollection<StudentRecordDetail> StudentRecords)
    {

        //Validate header record before proceeding

        if(! IsHeaderRecordValid)
            throw new Exception("Invalid Header Record Found.");
        const int buffersize = 20;
        var buffer1 = new BlockingCollection<FlattenedLoadDetail>(buffersize);
        var buffer2 = new BlockingCollection<FlattenedLoadDetail>(buffersize);
        var buffer3 = new BlockingCollection<FlattenedLoadDetail>(buffersize);
        var buffer4 = new BlockingCollection<FlattenedLoadDetail>(buffersize);
        var taskmonitor = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnCanceled);

        using (var loadUpStartBuffer = taskmonitor.StartNew(() => LoadBuffers(
            new List<BlockingCollection<FlattenedLoadDetail>>
            {buffer1, buffer2, buffer3, buffer4}, StudentRecords)))
        {
            var recordcreateDateValidationStage = taskmonitor.StartNew(() => ValidateRecordCreateDateActivity.Validate(buffer1));
            var uniqueStudentIDValidationStage =
                taskmonitor.StartNew(() => ValidateUniqueStudentIDActivity.Validate(buffer2));
            var SSNNumberRangeValidationStage =
                taskmonitor.StartNew(() => ValidateDocSequenceNumberActivity.Validate(buffer3));
            var SSNRecordNumberMatchValidationStage =
                taskmonitor.StartNew(() => ValidateStudentSSNRecordNumberActivity.Validate(buffer4));

            Task.WaitAll(loadUpStartBuffer, recordcreateDateValidationStage, uniqueStudentIDValidationStage,
                SSNNumberRangeValidationStage, SSNRecordNumberMatchValidationStage);

        }
    }
```

In fact, if I could tie up the tasks in such a way that once one fails, all the others stop, that would help me a lot but I am a newbie to this pattern and kind of trying to figure out best way to handle this problem I have here. Should I just throw caution to the wind and have each of the validation steps load an output buffer to be passed on to subsequent task? Is that a better way to go with this?

Comment: So do you want to know if an item passes all 5 checks, because currently you're getting 5 lists of the items that passed just that one check.  That seems...less useful.  Also, there isn't much of a pipeline here.  You pass each item to every step, they pass their results to the final result, and that's all.  A pipeline would imply each record is passed to the first validator, then the second, then the third, etc.

Comment: My intention here is to use the TaskContinuation option to interrupt in the case that an invalid item is found during any of the stages. I need to look through all the items to ensure that they all pass all validation stages, before I can push the data to the database. What I want here is to sort of speed things up by passing the same item, at the same time, to each of the validation stages so that rather than first doing StageA on item1, and then StageB on item1, and then StageC on item1, and so on, I can do all 5 concurrently and do the same on each of the other items concurrently.

Comment: You're overcomplicating the problem. You'd be better off using multiple threads, each of which does all five validation steps on a subset of records. `Parallel.ForEach` makes quick work of that. Your proposed solution will force you to write a lot of tedious and somewhat nasty code to collate the results from your separate threads.

Comment: But I don't need results from each of the tasks. During Validation, what really happens is a list of the records that fail the rule are compiled and each of them logged to a log file somewhere.A Flag is updated on each validation class to indicate whether or not failed records were found. if any of those flags were updated, the process stops and the user only needs to go to the log to see the problem with the data that was uploaded.

Comment: Ofcourse I would like to use the input/output example as in cool explaination of the pattern here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx , but I don't really need an output from each of the tasks, is why I thought to make copies of the original buffer and just pass it down to the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The first question you need to answer for yourself is whether you want to improve latency or throughput.

The strategy you depicted takes a single item and perform parallel calculation on it. This means that an item is serviced very fast, but at the expense of other items that are left waiting for their turn to enter.

Consider an alternative concurrent approach. You can treat the entire validation process as a sequential operation, but simultaneously service more than one item in parallel.

It seems to me that in your case you will benefit more from the latter approach, especially from the perspective of simplicity and since I am guessing that latency is not as important here.

Comment: I completely agree with you that the latter, theoretically, would benefit me more. But remember, I stated that during each validation stage, I do not really need to return data from each task.

Comment: So don't :-) the fact that they are independent means that you *can* execute them in parallel. It does not mean that you *should*.

Comment: I need to run each of the (average 30,000) records per day through all 5 validation steps in worst case, and I would very much like to ensure this is effectively. Why should I not use Parallel approach here?

Comment: I am not saying you should not parallelize. I am saying you should carefully choose what to parallelize. Having said that, did you actually perform a test and measured how much it costs to do it sequentially? In general, you should always optimize based on a concrete measurement that does not meet your requirements. Even then, you start with the simple things and raise the complexity of optimizations until you hit the desired performance.